# Why do some data loading tools work with professional edition?

Tags: api, data-loader, professional-edition, jitterbit, dataloader.io

When looking at the Salesforce [edition comparison chart](http://www.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf), it states that **Integration via Web services API** is only available if you pay for it.

Indeed, when I try to load data into my org using Apex Data Loader, it does not work, since I have no API access.
However, Dataloader.io and Jitterbit Data Loader do work with my professional edition, which is not what I would expect.

I see no technical reason why these tools work? Is there maybe some commercial agreement between them and Salesforce to skip this API limitation when the request comes from their application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a piece of documentation that goes over this in the ISVForce guide.

[API Access in Group and Professional Editions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_api_access.htm?search_text=API)

The first lines of text on that page read

> API access is not normally supported in GE and PE orgs. However, after your app passes the security review, you’re eligible to use some APIs for building composite applications.
>
> - Currently, the standard Data SOAP and REST APIs are supported for GE and PE apps, and Metadata API is supported in PE apps. To request API access, see How do I get an API token for my app? You can also contact Salesforce to request that a connected app be whitelisted to use the REST API in GE or PE orgs.
>
>   - Other APIs, such as the Bulk API and Apex methods exposed as SOAP Web services, remain unavailable.
>   - You can enable REST-based Web services using connected app consumer whitelisting.
>   - You can enable SOAP-based Web services, including Metadata API, using an API token called a Client ID, which is appended to your SOAP headers in integration calls. This special key enables your app to make calls to GE and PE orgs for Data API and PE orgs for Metadata API, even if the customer does not have API access.